# Regular expression to get specific pages out of a list of landing pages in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I need to select landing pages for each hotel my client operates. Hotel pages are identified by the string `/hotels-in-XYZ/`.

- I need to exclude all other pages
- I need to exclude sub pages like `/hotels-in-XYZ/offer-page/` too

Sample list of hotels:

```
/XXX-one/login/
/hotels-in-ranthambhore/
/hotels-in-jaipur-resort/
/hotels-in-morocco-marrakech/
/about-us/
/hotels-in-mumbai/
/hotels-in-bengaluru/
/hotels-in-agra-resort/special-offers/extended-stay-offer/
/hotels-in-shimla/amp/
/hotels-in-udaipur-resort/amp/
```

I'm not that familiar with regex and I've been googling to find a solution. The closest I have is `.*?\/hotels(.*)\/.*` but it does not exclude page like `/hotels-in-shimla/amp/`

Your help would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to post any additional information to explain the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `^\/hotels-in-[\w\-]+\/$` work for you?

I tested this at https://regex101.com/r/9c2IRC/1/

Comment: Its close but its ignoring certain hotels like `/hotels-in-jaipur-resort/` and 
`/hotels-in-morocco-marrakech/`. Any idea how to include those too?

Comment: I updated the regex and the example at regex101.com to include the hyphen character. Please have a look.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for your help :)